# Are topology of Grassmanian as a variety and as a manifold the same?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

We can see Grassmannian as a projective variety by embedding it into projective space. Also, we can think of it as a manifold. Do these two different viewpoints give the same topology or not?

Comment: They're very far apart (unless the Grassmanian is trivial) - the manifold topology is Hausdorff, while in the Zariski topology, every two nonempty open sets intersect nontrivially.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you! I forgot the basic facts you pointed out..

Comment: @KReiser Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost ok, I put the comment in to an answer. For better or worse, there's a long history of folks in the algebraic-geometry tag solving one-liners in a comment instead of writing an answer.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you! I know that many questions are answered in form of comments. But this does not make it **visible in the question queue**
that it has alredy been answered. If you click at "Unanswered", you will read something like "269,170 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers, although many of them are actually answered in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're very far apart (unless the Grassmanian is trivial) - the manifold topology is Hausdorff, while in the Zariski topology, every two nonempty open sets intersect nontrivially as the Grassmanian is irreducible.

Comment: Sorry for the late accepts.